# Grunt task fails in jenkins : Error Spawn Enoent?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, gruntjs, intern

I am trying to build my intern test in Jenkins(slave) using grunt. The grunt files performs certain functions one of which is failing. The error that I get is because it fails to start the sample. The error in the jenkins console

```
[4mRunning "unzip:sample" (unzip) task[24m
Created "./sample" directory
[4mRunning "exec:start-sample" (exec) task[24m
[31m>> [39mFailed with: Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
[33mWarning: Task "exec:start-sample" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
```

This is the console where there was no error

```
[4mRunning "unzip:sample" (unzip) task[24m
Created "./sample" directory
[4mRunning "exec:start-sample" (exec) task[24m
[4mRunning "wait:45" (wait) task[24m
```

GruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            exec: {
                'start-sample': {
                   cmd: 'start serverstart.exe -z ../../sample',
                   cwd: '../../WEB-INF/bin64'
                },
                'stop-sample' : {
                    cmd: 'start serverstop.exe -n "Sample" -user abc -pwd abc',
                    cwd: '../../WEB-INF/bin64'
                }
            },
            unzip: {
                'sample' : {
                    src : '../../sample.zip',
                    dest : './sample'
                }
            }
        )};

        grunt.registerTask('run-tests', 'call tasks needed for test setup, testing, and teardown', 
            function(suite) {
               if (!suite) {
                   throw new Error('A suite name argument is required with the "it" task');
               }
               if(suite != 'unit'){
                   grunt.task.run([ 'get-sample', 'start-sample', 'wait:45']);
               }
       });

       grunt.registerTask('get-sample', "unzips the sample server", [ 'unzip-sample' ]);
       grunt.registerTask('start-sample', "starts sample server", [ 'exec:start-sample' ]);
       grunt.registerTask('stop-sample', "stops sample server", [ 'exec:stop-sample' ]);

       // By default we just test
       grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'run-tests:all' ]);

}
```

How do i debug gruntfile in jenkins ? What is causing the sample service to not start?

Comment: `ENOENT` means the folder cannot be found. In that case it might be because you don't have access to it. Can you make sure your task is running with elevated priviledges ?

Comment: How do I check if tasks have required privilege ? For one I know that the VM that I am running this on has administrator privilege